# How do I enable Apollo Tracing with Hot Chocolate for a particular query request?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

Sometimes I would like to be able to enable *Apollo Tracing* for a very specific query request because this particular request is slow for instance. Is there a way to do this with [Hot Chocolate](https://hotchocolate.io)? And if yes, how would I tell a specific query request that I’m interested in tracing actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, yes *Hot Chocolate* does support *Apollo Tracing* on demand which means on a per query request base. It just needs a little configuration tweak on the server-side.

Usually, you would create a *GraphQL* schema like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Here I register my services / repositories; omitted for brevity

        services.AddGraphQL(sp => Schema.Create(c =>
        {
            // Here I register my schema types and so on; omitted for brevity
        }));
    }

     // Code omitted for brevity
}
```

To enable tracing on demand, you need to set the `TracingPreference` option to `TracingPreference.OnDemand`. The previous code fragment would then look like this.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Here I register my services / repositories; omitted for brevity

        services.AddGraphQL(sp => Schema.Create(c =>
        {
            // Here I register my schema types and so on; omitted for brevity
        }),
        new QueryExecutionOptions
        {
            TracingPreference = TracingPreference.OnDemand
        });
    }

     // Code omitted for brevity
}
```

After you have set the tracing preference to `OnDemand`, you just need to pass the following HTTP header `GraphQL-Tracing=1` with every query request you’re interested in. That's all.

For more information about *Apollo Tracing*, head over [here](https://hotchocolate.io/docs/apollo-tracing).